# Simultaneously diagonalization of two matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix and $B$ a real positive-definite matrix. Is it possible to simultaneously diagonalize of $A$ and $B$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Some times. For instance if they're both diagonal matrices they are simultaneously diagonalisable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you consider $A,B$ as quadratic forms, then, of course, they are simultaneously diagonalizable. That is, there is an invertible $S$ s.t. $S^TBS=I,S^TAS=D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

Proof: diagonalize $B$ and $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$. Since $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ is symmetric, there is an orthogonal $O$ s.t. $O^TB^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}O=D$ where $D$ is diagonal. Finally take $S=B^{-1/2}O$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if and only if they have the same eigenvectors.

Equivalently, if and only if they commute.

Comment: Not "have the same eigenvectors", but "admit a basis of common eigenvectors". Take for instance $B=I$ and $A$ not a scalar matrix. Commutation is a correct (and simpler) if and only if condition.

Comment: But still, they do have the same eigenvectors!

Comment: No they don't. The only reasonable meaning for having "the same eigenvectors" is having the same set of eigenvectors. One wouldn't say two polynomials $P,Q$ have the same roots unless _every_ root of $P$ is a root of $Q$ and vice versa. A far-fetched alternative interpretation could be: having _some_ common eigenvector (but "share an eigenvector" without plural would then be much clearer), but this does not give a necessary and sufficient condition either. Just try to define what you mean by having the same eigenvectors.