# $\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ where $A$ is low rank and has a subset of eigenvalues from $B^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, trace, positive-definite

Most of the question is in the title.
Suppose that I have $B$ a square $N\times N$ positive definite matrix, and $A$ a low-rank square matrix with its non-zero eigenvalues being a subset of the spectrum of $B^{-1}$. Is there a simple way to compute the trace : $\mathrm{tr}(BA)$?

My intuition is that if $M$ is the rank of $A$, then $B$ and $A$ can share all $N$ eigenvectors and that one can diagonalize $A$ and $B$ and get automatically $\mathrm{tr}(BA) = \sum_{i:\lambda_i>0} \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i} = M$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. But I am not sure how to obtain the proper ordering etc.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Without more information about the eigenvectors of $A$, there is no way to take advantage of the eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: Cost of computing $\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ directly it is $2N^2$ floating point operations. Even having rank factorization $A = KL$ will not allow for any speed up.

Comment: I am not interested in any speed up but I want to find a bound or even better an equality :)

Answer (score 2):

Without further information, there is no way to use the eigenvalues of $A$ in this computation. However, we can make use of the fact that $A$ is low-rank. In particular, if $A = CF$ is a rank factorization (so that $C$ is $N \times r$ and $F$ is $r \times N$), then we have
$$
\operatorname{tr}(BA) = 
\operatorname{tr}(BCF) = \operatorname{tr}(FBC).
$$
That is, we may rewrite the expression as the trace of an $r \times r$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is a more concrete attempt.
So if the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}$ are $\Lambda_B = \{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^N$, I know that the eigenvalues $\Lambda_A$ of $A$ are a subset of $\Lambda_B$ and the rest are $0$.
So I can rewrite $B=W D_B^{-1}W^\top$ where $D_B=\text{diag}(\Lambda_A, \Lambda_{B}/\Lambda_{A})$ and $W$ are the corresponding eigenvectors.
Similarly I can rewrite $A$ as $A=WD_AW^\top$ where $D_A=\text{diag}(\Lambda_A, 0)$

Which means I can rewrite
\begin{align}
\text{tr}(BA) =& \text{tr}(WD_B^{-1}W^\top WD_AW^\top) = \text{tr}(W^\top W D_B^{-1}D_A)\\
=& \text{tr}(D_B^{-1}D_A) = \sum_{i=i}^M \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i} = M.
\end{align}

Is there anything wrong with my reasonning?

Comment: The fact that you assume that we have $B = WD_B^{-1}W^\top$ and $A = WD_AW^\top$ for a single orthogonal matrix $W$ means that you assume that $A$ and $B$ are **simultaneously diagonalizable**. Equivalently, you're assuming that $AB = BA$. From what you said in the question, we have no reason to believe that this is the case.

Comment: Well $B$ is positive definite and $A$ is positive semi-definite right? So both matrices are symmetric and  $AB = BA$ ?

Comment: I just saw https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079627/simultaneously-diagonalization-of-two-matrices and it seems that I need my matrices to have the same eigenvectors. Which is automatically the case here.

Comment: You seem to be saying that for every positive definite $A$ and positive semidefinite $B$, we have $AB = BA$. This is **not** true. For example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$

Comment: You're right! Sorry my first comment is completely wrong. However the second one holds I think.

Comment: Are you saying that, for your particular example, $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes, and this is due to the fact the $M$ non-negative values of $A$ are the same as $B^{-1}$.
There are $M$ common eigenvectors, and the $N-M$ others have eigenvalues $0$ therefore they can be anything as long as they are orthogonal to the first $M$ ones, so I can chose them to be the $N-M$ other eigenvectors of $B^{-1}$

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you can "choose" them to be certain eigenvectors? For the $A,B$ from your example, either it holds that $AB = BA$ or it doesn't hold. If $AB = BA$, then it can be said that $A,B$ have "the same eigenvectros". If $AB \neq BA$, then this cannot be said.

Comment: And why are there $M$ common eigenvectors? Do you have information about $A$ and $B$ that you didn't include in the question?

Comment: Do you have any information that rules out an example like
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}, \quad B  = \pmatrix{1/2&0\\0&1}?
$$